# Showing a Result Table based on an array of Radio Buttons selected

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement

I am new to coding. I'm trying to build an online form where there are a few questions that user will need to answer and questions are done in radio button options. Based on the array of radio buttons selected, I will then need to show the results on the same page. I'm thinking of using if..else statement but it doesn't seem to be working.

Here is my code:

```
<script>

function ShowHideDiv() {

    if (document.getElementById("chkCitizen").checked ? && document.getElementById("chkMale").checked ?
    && document.getElementById("chkSingle").checked ? && document.getElementById("chkEmployed").checked ?
    && document.getElementById("chkNo").checked ? )
    {
        btn1.style.visibility = "visible";
            var dvtext = document.getElementById("dvtext");
            dvtext.style.display = "block" : "none";
    }
    else if (document.getElementById("chkCitizen") && document.getElementById("chkFemale")
    && document.getElementById("chkSingle") && document.getElementById("chkEmployed")
    && document.getElementById("chkNo")
    {
        btn1.style.visibility = "visible";
            var dvtext = document.getElementById("dvtext");
            dvtext.style.display = "block" : "none";
    }
}


function resetFunction(){
    document.getElementById("reliefChecker").reset();
}



</script>
```

Here's the full code with html and css:

```js
<script>

function ShowHideDiv() {

    if (document.getElementById("chkCitizen").checked && document.getElementById("chkMale").checked
    && document.getElementById("chkSingle").checked && document.getElementById("chkEmployed").checked
    && document.getElementById("chkNo").checked)
    {
        btn1.style.visibility = "visible";
        var btn1 = document.getElementById("btn1");
            var dvtext = document.getElementById("dvtext");
            dvtext.style.display = "block" : "none";
    }
    else if (document.getElementById("chkCitizen").checked && document.getElementById("chkFemale").checked
    && document.getElementById("chkSingle").checked && document.getElementById("chkEmployed").checked
    && document.getElementById("chkNo").checked)
    {
        btn1.style.visibility = "visible";
        var btn1 = document.getElementById("btn1");
            var dvtext = document.getElementById("dvtext");
            dvtext.style.display = "block" : "none";
    }
    else if (document.getElementById("chkPR").checked && document.getElementById("chkMale").checked
    && document.getElementById("chkSingle").checked && document.getElementById("chkEmployed").checked
    && document.getElementById("chkNo").checked)
    {
        btn1.style.visibility = "visible";
        var btn1 = document.getElementById("btn1");
            var dvtext = document.getElementById("dvtext");
            dvtext.style.display = "block" : "none";
    }
    else if (document.getElementById("chkPR").checked && document.getElementById("chkFemale").checked 
    && document.getElementById("chkSingle").checked && document.getElementById("chkEmployed").checked 
    && document.getElementById("chkNo").checked)
    {
        btn1.style.visibility = "visible";
        var btn1 = document.getElementById("btn1");
            var dvtext = document.getElementById("dvtext");
            dvtext.style.display = "block" : "none";
    }
    else if (document.getElementById("chkForeigner").checked && document.getElementById("chkMale").checked 
    && document.getElementById("chkSingle").checked && document.getElementById("chkEmployed").checked 
    && document.getElementById("chkNo").checked)
    {
        btn1.style.visibility = "visible";
        var btn1 = document.getElementById("btn1");
            var dvtext = document.getElementById("dvtext");
            dvtext.style.display = "block" : "none";
    }
    else (document.getElementById("chkForeigner").checked && document.getElementById("chkFemale").checked
    && document.getElementById("chkSingle").checked && document.getElementById("chkEmployed").checked
    && document.getElementById("chkNo").checked)
    {
        btn1.style.visibility = "visible";
        var btn1 = document.getElementById("btn1");
            var dvtext = document.getElementById("dvtext");
            dvtext.style.display = "block" : "none";
    }
}

function resetFunction(){
    document.getElementById("reliefChecker").reset();
}

</script>
```

```css
.button {
    background-color: #F7922C;
    border-radius: 12px;
    border: 2px solid white;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 40px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    visibility: block;
    }
.buttonReset {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 12px;
    border: 2px solid #005AAD;
    color: black;
    padding: 10px 40px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    visibility: hidden;
    }
.center {
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<h1><p style="font-family:Arial">Checker</p></h1>


<form id="reliefChecker">
<fieldset id="reliefChecker"; style="padding:10px;border:0px solid #FFFFFF;">


<!-- Second Question -->
<p style="font-family:Arial; font-size:25px;font-weight:bold"> 
        Gender <span style="color:red">*</span></p>

<label for="chkMale" style="font-family:Arial; font-size:20px;">
<input type="radio" id="chkMale" name="gender" value="male" onclick="ShowHideDiv()">
    Male</label>
<br>
<label for="chkFemale" style="font-family:Arial; font-size:20px;">
    <input type="radio" id="chkFemale" name="gender" value="female" onclick="ShowHideDiv()">
    Female</label>

<!-- Third Question -->
<p style="font-family:Arial; font-size:25px;font-weight:bold"> 
        Marital Status <span style="color:red">*</span></p>

<label for="chkMarried" style="font-family:Arial; font-size:20px;">
<input type="radio" id="chkMarried" name="maritalStatus" value="married" onclick="ShowHideDiv()">
    Married</label>
<br>
<label for="chkSingle" style="font-family:Arial; font-size:20px;">
    <input type="radio" id="chkSingle" name="maritalStatus" value="single" onclick="ShowHideDiv()">
    Single</label>
<br>
<label for="chkDivorced" style="font-family:Arial; font-size:20px;">
    <input type="radio" id="chkDivorced" name="maritalStatus" value="divorce" onclick="ShowHideDiv()">
    Divorced</label>


<!-- Fourth Question -->
<p style="font-family:Arial; font-size:25px;font-weight:bold"> 
        Employment Status <span style="color:red">*</span></p>

<label for="chkEmployed" style="font-family:Arial; font-size:20px;">
<input type="radio" id="chkEmployed" name="EmploymentStatus" value="employed" onclick="ShowHideDiv()">
    Employee / Self-Employed (Including Part-Timers)</label>
<br>
<label for="chkUnemployed" style="font-family:Arial; font-size:20px;">
    <input type="radio" id="chkUnemployed" name="EmploymentStatus" value="unemployed" onclick="ShowHideDiv()">
    Unemployed</label>

<!-- Fifth Question -->
<p style="font-family:Arial; font-size:25px;font-weight:bold"> 
        Do you have any children? <span style="color:red">*</span></p>

<label for="chkYes" style="font-family:Arial; font-size:20px;">
<input type="radio" id="chkYes" name="Children" value="yes">
    Yes</label>
<br>
<label for="chkNo" style="font-family:Arial; font-size:20px;">
    <input type="radio" id="chkNo" name="Children" value="no" onclick="ShowHideDiv()">
    No</label>


<br><br>
<div class="center">
    <input type="button" id="btn1" class="button center" value="Check Now" onclick="ShowHideDiv()">
</div>

    
<div id="dvtext" style="padding:20px;border:1px solid lightgray; border-radius:15px; margin:15px; background-color:#FFFAC7; font-size:22px; font-family:Arial;display:none"> 
<span style="font-size:24px"><b><u>Results</u></b></span>
<br><br>
Show some results here!


<div class="center">
    <input type="button" id="btnreset1" class="buttonReset center" value="Reset" onclick="ShowHideDiv(); resetFunction()">
</div>



</fieldset>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you show your html for the radio buttons?

Comment: Hi.. I have edited my qs above with html

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one (as I understood, it works fine (if you have more questions, it can be done with loops) ).

HTML code is:

```
<div class="questions">
    <div class="question"> Question 1
        <label>
            <input class="answer" type="radio" name="q1" value="one">One
        </label>
        <label>
            <input class="answer" type="radio" name="q1" value="two">Two
        </label>
        <label>
            <input class="answer" type="radio" name="q1" value="three">Three
        </label>
        <label>
            <input class="answer" type="radio" name="q1" value="four">Four
        </label>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="question"> Question 2
        <label>
            <input class="answer" type="radio" name="q2" value="one">One
        </label>
        <label>
            <input class="answer" type="radio" name="q2" value="two">Two
        </label>
        <label>
            <input class="answer" type="radio" name="q2" value="three">Three
        </label>
        <label>
            <input class="answer" type="radio" name="q2" value="four">Four
        </label>
    </div>
 </div>

 <br>
 <button id="submit">Submit</button>
```

CSS code is:

```
.question {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

JS code is:

```
var submit = document.getElementById('submit');

submit.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var answers = document.getElementsByClassName('answer');
    var result = "";
    for(var i=0; i<answers.length; i++) {
        if (answers[i].checked) { 
            result += answers[i].value + "\n";
        }
    }
    alert(result);
});
```

Comment: Hi There! thank you for this but it is not exactly what I was looking for. I have edited my qs above.. maybe that'll make it clearer?

Comment: What do you want to do when the button clicked ?

Comment: Display a Div Text below to inform user what they should do next

Comment: Sorry I could not get what is your point. Do you mean that you are trying to show checked results? (It would be better if you describe your problem, maybe with pictures or something)

Comment: Unfortunately I am unable to upload the picture (work laptop thus the constraints) but basically this form is to check what type of policies the user are able to claim or buy. Thus, the form is supposed to ask them questions about their employment and marital status and such.. after which.. a text is supposed to be displayed below to tell them of the relevant policies.. for eg "You are eligible for Life Insurance Policy"

Comment: So the button i created in the form points back to the ShowHideDiv() function to check which radio buttons has been selected then show the "Results" below.. Results being what type of policies they are eligible for.

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div class="questions">
    <div class="question"> Question 1
        <label>
            <input class="answer" type="radio" name="q1" value="one">One
        </label>
        <label>
            <input class="answer" type="radio" name="q1" value="two">Two
        </label>
        <label>
            <input class="answer" type="radio" name="q1" value="three">Three
        </label>
        <label>
            <input class="answer" type="radio" name="q1" value="four">Four
        </label>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="question"> Question 2
        <label>
            <input class="answer" type="radio" name="q2" value="one">One
        </label>
        <label>
            <input class="answer" type="radio" name="q2" value="two">Two
        </label>
        <label>
            <input class="answer" type="radio" name="q2" value="three">Three
        </label>
        <label>
            <input class="answer" type="radio" name="q2" value="four">Four
        </label>
    </div>
    <br>
    <button id="submit">Submit</button>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.question {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

JS

```
var submit = document.getElementById('submit');
var result = document.getElementById('result');
var resultText = document.getElementById('result-text');
var questions = document.getElementsByClassName('questions')[0];

submit.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var answers = document.getElementsByClassName('answer');
    var r = "";
    for(var i=0; i<answers.length; i++) {
        if (answers[i].checked) { 
            r += answers[i].value + "\n";
        }
    }
    questions.style.display = 'none';
    result.style.height = '300px';
    resultText.innerHTML = r;
});
```